Why am I getting this error- Sorry, there's been a disconnect. We can't get that information right now. Either try again or check our support page
I'm trying to create a custom connector to Databricks from PowerApps. I don't get this error on signing in to Powerapps Studio but only on trying to create a custom connector. I'm logging in incognito and have tried to do this in Chrome and Edge with the same result. Are these factors the reason I'm getting this error or is there any other reason?
